# Implementing NSValueTransformer for Transformable attributes in Swift

Tags: core-data, swift

I'm trying to implement a NSValue Transformer, which should help me to save a Double Array into Core Data using  a Transformable attribute.

So I tried to implement the transformedValueClass. But NSArray.class() is crossed out. Unfortunately I didn't find a reason for this.

My method looks like this:

```
class PacePerK:NSValueTransformer{
    class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass!
    {
        return NSArray.class()
    }
}
```

I get the following compiler errors:
Expected member name following '.'
Expected identifier in class declaration

Unfortunately they don't really help me.

Why is the NSArray.class crossed out?
How can I return the class of NSArray without causing a compiler error?

Answer (score 5):

It appears the correct why to reference class objects in Swift is with:

```
NSArray.self
```

Also, in your example, you’ll need to mark your transformedValueClass function with “override”.  So:

```
class PacePerK:NSValueTransformer{
    override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass!
    {
        return NSArray.self
    }
}
```