# Where to implement NSValueTransformer for Core Data in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-data, nsvaluetransformer

I'm trying to put entities in a Core Data store that each have non-standard data types - one is an NSDocument and the other is an NSURL. I get that within the .xcdatamodeld I need to declare them as Transformable. And I *think* I need to add something that implements NSValueTransformer to turn them into NSData (... or is there a default transformer that will do that automatically?)

I think the question should be simple to answer: where do I implement it? I haven't found an explicit example of doing this in Swift. There's an [Objective-C example](http://lextech.com/2013/01/core-data-transformable-attributes/) but the separation of .h and .m files makes it unclear to me where this would go in Swift.

Suppose I have an entity type called Notebook with an attribute called folderURL - of type Transformable in the database, and of type NSURL in the actual variable. (I'm using that as the example because it's the simpler one - please don't tell me to just convert the NSURL to a String, because that won't work for the other Transformable.)

Question is: where do I put the NSValueTransformer for folderURL, assuming that I need one? Should Notebook implement it? Should Notebook+CoreDataProperties? Or do I need a separate subclass called FolderURL that implements it, and if so, how do I refer to that subclass back in Notebook (and/or Notebook+CoreDataProperties)?

(There was an earlier question with a [similar title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229919/implementing-nsvaluetransformer-for-transformable-attributes-in-swift) but they seem to have got a bit further than this already - they're not asking or demonstrating about the "where".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "where" is just anywhere in your project. Anywhere that ensures that your `NSValueTransformer` subclass will exist at run time. Implement the `NSValueTransformer` subclass, and enter the class name in the Core Data model as the value transformer.

However there **is** a default transformer. Any class that adopts the `NSCoding` protocol can be automatically transformed by Core Data. In that case you mark the attribute as transformable but don't include a class name. This includes `NSURL`, so you don't need to transform that or convert it to a string.

For your `NSDocument` subclass then, you have the option of either implementing `NSCoding` in the class or of implementing an `NSValueTransformer` subclass for the document type.